# Disable image cache in OpenCart

Tags: php, image, caching, resize, opencart

I am currently developing an iPad/tablet optimized template of OpenCart.

I have stumbled upon a problem here, all images I am wanting to use are all cached and resized images, and on the iPad template I want the original resolution images to be displayed, especially the main image.

Is there a way I can get the template to show the original uploaded images instead of the resized images? If someone can point me into the right direction I will develop a vqMod for it (as I still want to use the resuzed images for the main website)!

Many thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you will need to do it is to use either HTTP_IMAGE or HTTPS_IMAGE depending on the ssl status. For the main image, it's pretty simple, you basically need to use

```
<?php echo HTTP_IMAGE . $product_info['image']; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Jay, I'm currently out just now so I can't test it, thanks for the answer, I know your an OpenCart expert.  Is the variable for the product defonatly $prod_info, or just $product? And will this load the thumbnail image?

Comment: It's `$prod_info` definitely, and no it will load the full image as uploaded

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look soon and let you know how I get one.  Cheers

Comment: It was $product_info['image'], not prod_info, thanks though, its working great now. I updated the answer for you :)