# Opencart 3 Add Additional Delivery Detail

Tags: opencart, checkout

I need to add additional delivery option in the delivery detail of Opencart 3's checkout page.

I found the file in > catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/shipping_address.twig

I tried modify but not visual change in the checkout page.

Can anyone guide me to the correct file ?

Note: currently im using default template.

Comment: have you refresh developer cache after your changes ? if not. So, please refresh developer cache & then check it. please see here for more details refresh cache- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220327/disable-template-caching-for-development-in-opencart-3

Comment: Thank you HarnishDesign, it is work now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file, named "install.xml" and then zip it. Then install it as module from extension upload. And then refresh cache from "Modifications".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
<name>Additional Delivery Detail</name>
<code>delivery</code>
<version>1.0</version>
<author>white coffeee</author>
<link></link>

<file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/shipping_address.twig">
<operation>
    <search><![CDATA[         **CODE TO BE SEARCHED**       ]></search>
    <add position="after"><![CDATA[         


      **CODE TO BE ADDED**


    ]]></add>
</operation>
</file>
</modification>
```