# Display username in top header and my account dropdown after user is logged in at opencart 3.0 template

Tags: twig, opencart-3

I am working out `catalog/theme/customtemplate/template/header/header1.twig`

also at `catalog/controller/acount/account.php`

but i 'm unable to get the output. So what i have to add and at which files?

Answer (score 2):

In `catalog/controller/common/header.php` add the following code for Customer First & last name.

```
$data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
$data['customer_lastname'] = $this->customer->getLastName();
```

In `catalog/view/theme/your-theme/template/common/header.twig` & then add following code for the first and last name.

```
{{ customer_firstname }}
{{ customer_lastname }}
```

Please refresh developer cache after changes & then check it. please see here for more details refresh cache - [Disable template caching for development in OpenCart 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220327/disable-template-caching-for-development-in-opencart-3)

Answer (score 2):

It would better if you first check if the **customer is logged in**.
The code could return errors if the customer is not logged in.

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
   $data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
   $data['customer_lastname'] = $this->customer->getLastName();
   }
```