# Add Images to a theme on opencart

Tags: opencart

I'm been trying to add a GIF image to my opencart theme just underneath the search bar but can't seem to find the right file to edit and where to add the image so the code finds it

could do with some help went through all the files I can thing of and still not getting any further

Answer (score 0):

Kindly mention which Opencart version are you using? You can find the search file in the

```
\catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\search.tpl **OR** search.twig
```

folder. Don't forget to clear cache if you are you using latest opencart version.

Comment: Hiya yeah that didn't workso i decided to add it to the background file which works fine so should solve the problem but rhank you for the help

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220327/disable-template-caching-for-development-in-opencart-3 Maybe this will help you. Upvote if you can help this.

Answer (score 0):

What theme are you using? You'd likely need to change the upload/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.twig or upload/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/home.twig file, if you're using the default theme. Also, if you want, you can put it in the upload/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/search.twig file.

FYI: You'd be best to turn off opencart's cache system. This can be done via the admin by clicking on the cog wheel (top right).